# What does " ~$ " prefixed in front of file mean?

Tags: git, directory, ms-word, prefix

Two weeks ago I had some Git merging issues due to what I think, rebasing to a old version. I didn't notice it at first, I noticed that my whole folder was screwed up to an outdated version.

After some struggle I managed to get back to the clean state I was before. However, today I noticed one folder had deleted files prefixed with "~$".
I can't open them and I know they're outdated. I also see a file called: "~WRL0005.tmp" which I didn't have before.

[image]

Does any one know what this means? And does this possibly mean that there's somehow still a danger to fall back to an old version of my repo?

Comment: Those `~$`-prefixed files look like owner files created by Microsoft Word when you had those documents open. Perhaps you used Git to commit while you had Word open, which would explain why those files might've been put into version control. [Here's an article if you want to read more about them.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211632/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files) You can probably delete them from version control.

Answer (score 2):

You should:

- delete (git rm) those temporary files from your repository
- update your `.gitignore` file with [Microsoft Word ignore rules](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/MicrosoftOffice.gitignore)

For instance:

```
*.tmp

# Word temporary
~$*.doc*

# Word Auto Backup File
Backup of *.doc*
```

That way, you are sure no more of those files will be added by mistake to your repository.